# Problem displays days of the week in certain languages using GetLocaleInfoEx — Cebuano, Tagalog

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, locale

I have these language identifiers (that up until now I have been using for HTML language codes):

```
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("en")); // English
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("de")); // German
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("es")); // Spanish
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("it")); // Italian
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("pl")); // Polish
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("fr")); // French
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("pt")); // Portuguese Brazil
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("nl")); // Dutch
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("sv")); // Swedish
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("sl")); // Slovenian
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("cs")); // Czech
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("fi")); // Finnish
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("da")); // Danish
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("uk")); // Ukranian
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ru")); // Russian
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("tl")); // Tagalog
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ht")); // Hatian Creole
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("af")); // Afrikaans
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("sq")); // Albanian
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("zh-Hans")); // Chinese Simplified
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("hr")); // Croatian
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("tr")); // Turkish
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("tw")); // Twi
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("sw")); // Swahili
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("et")); // Estonian
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ro")); // Romanian
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("el")); // Greek
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("bg")); // Bulgarian
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("mg")); // Malagasy
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ar")); // Arabic
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("id")); // Indonesian
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("hi")); // Hindi
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ta")); // Tamil
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("vi")); // Vietnamese
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("zu")); // Zulu
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("guw")); // Gun 
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ln")); // Lingala
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("pt")); // Portuguese Portugal
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("pa")); // Punjabi
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("mt")); // Maltese
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("hu")); // Hungarian
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("fr")); // Saramaccan (uses French)
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("am")); // Amharic
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ja")); // Japanese
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("tn")); // Setswana
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("srn")); // Sranantongo
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("drk")); // Aukan
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("hy")); // Armenian
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("gu")); // Gujarati
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("st")); // Sesotho
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ceb")); // Cebuano
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ts"));  // Tsonga
```

I decided to try and use the above codes for displaying the days of the week:

```
CString     strDay;
TCHAR       szDay[_MAX_PATH];
int         iDay;
// note:
// 1 is monday,
// 2 is tuesday etc..
// 7 is sunday
LCTYPE      lcDay[] =
{
    LOCALE_SDAYNAME7,
    LOCALE_SDAYNAME1,
    LOCALE_SDAYNAME2,
    LOCALE_SDAYNAME3,
    LOCALE_SDAYNAME4,
    LOCALE_SDAYNAME5,
    LOCALE_SDAYNAME6
};

for(iDay = 0; iDay < 7; iDay++)
{
    {
        GetLocaleInfoEx(theApp.GetHtmlLanguageCode(),
            lcDay[iDay],
            szDay,
            _MAX_PATH);
        strDay = szDay;
    }

    m_cbDays.AddString(strDay);
}
```

The above code works correctly for all languages except:

```
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("drk")); // Aukan
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ceb")); // Cebuano
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("guw")); // Gun 
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("ht"));  // Hatian Creole
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("srn")); // Sranantongo
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("tl"));  // Tagalog
aryStrLangId.Add(_T("tw"));  // Twi
```

How can I  use `GetLocaleInfoEx` to display the days of the week in those languages?

I tried using for example `twi` instead of `tw` and it made no difference.

Comment: Some of those codes aren't in the official [Codes for the Representation of Names of Languages](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php) list.

Comment: @IInspectable Fair enough. But `ceb`, `srn` and `twi` do. I tried `hat` instead of `ht` and it still showed English. For now I have added a manual override to fill the days in myself for these affected languages.

Comment: As an experiment, have you tried using the standard C++ locale implementation to get the weekday representations (e.g. [std::time_get::get_weekday](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/time_get/get_weekday))?

Comment: @IInspectable No. I have never used that method. Will look.

Comment: @IInspectable That API look complicated to me. What I have works so I won't break it. Thanks though.